# How to setup a wireless configuration at a central location for a set of devices having different operating system?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to setup a wireless router which is accessed by all the devices like desktops, laptops, tablets and/or phones running different operating systems in our network.

If have to setup the wireless configuration for individual client then it becomes too tedious. I don't have a domain based network in place.

Is it possible to setup the wireless configuration at a central location using any approach?

EDIT: Let me add additional information to this question. Basically my problem is, let's say system administrator sends a email "You have to add following settings to your wireless network so that you can connect your laptop to wireless network.."

1. Right click on WirelessNetwork-> Properties
2. Security Type: WPA2-Whatever
3. Encryption Type: AES
4. Network authenticcation method: Microsoft Protected EAP (PEAP)
5. Settings->Authentication method: EAP-MSCHAP v2
6. Configure..->When connecting: uncheck
   .......and many more settings!

Then basically I have to locate all these settings and enable and disable many things. Just imagine if these settings need to be applied for 100's of laptop?

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question;** Yes, it is possible.

Most routers can be administered from remotely via an IP address. These functions typically include wireless activation, setup and administration. Once setup, devices can access the wireless network. Depending how you setup the network, you should not necessarily have to setup each individual client.

Problem with your question is, you have given so little information about what equipment you are working with there is no way anyone can give you any specific guidance. I would recommend reading the manual for your specific router. If you do not have the manual, they are often available online.